# How can I use the Skyrim console with a notebook keyboard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I would like to use `setstage C06 1` command in Skyrim's console, to solve a glitch with the companion quest line. However, I'm using a notebook, and my tilde key is actually my <kbd>0</kbd> key too, so when I type <kbd>0</kbd>, it quits the console interface.

I tried copying and pasting from outside the game into the console, but that doesn't seem to work, either. The Windows virtual keyboard doesn't help, as well.

How can I type this command?

Comment: a picture of your keyboard would help, but you likely need to hold down a function key

Comment: This is going to be tough to generalize and not be too localized. Netbooks and notebooks can have different ways of making the tilde (~) function depending on various keyboard layouts.

Comment: Okay, I never knew, but there is actually a NumLock function available on my keyboard (although its well hidden), and thus there is a second set of number keys, which solved the problem. Thx guys!

Comment: @Attila Would you mind posting what kind of keyboard you have (a screenshot would be nice) and how you fixed it as an answer, so that others with the same problem can find the solution easier?

Comment: @Arkive — It sounds like [M'ivy's second option](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36770/how-can-i-use-the-skyrim-console-with-a-notebook-keyboard/36815#36815) is what did the trick.  On laptop keyboards, NumLock is usually toggled via Fn.  Attila, if I'm right, could you mark M'ivy's answer as correct, for future visitors?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your computer or the game understand the same code for 0 and ~

I see three workaround:

- add an external keyboard or numpad
- use integrated numpad if available (FN-keys)
- Change the keyboard mapping to one which does not generate this ambiguity (hopefully, international keyboards varies a lot for punctuations)

Comment: This is caused by Skyrim using normal input methods for the console's text input, but using hardware scan codes to *open* the console.  If you do try changing the keyboard mapping, you need one which moves `0`, not `~`.